# PHP Dynamically Creating Nested Elements

Tags: php, dynamically-generated, multidimensional-array

I am creating an array from a query using various tables that gives me a variable number of parents each containing a variable number of values.

For simplicity, say I have the following (using p as parent and v as value):

```
$parent[0] = array("p1v1","p1v2");  
$parent[1] = array("p2v1","p2v2","p2v3");  
$parent[2] = array("p3v1","p3v2");
```

I need to created the following tree:

- p1v1

  - p2v1

    - p3v1
    - p3v2
  - p2v2

    - p3v1
    - p3v2
  - p2v3

    - p3v1
    - p3v2
- p1v2

  - p2v1

    - p3v1
    - p3v2
  - p2v2

    - p3v1
    - p3v2
  - p2v3

    - p3v1
    - p3v2

Nested foreach loops:

```
foreach ($parent[0] as $key1 => $value1) {
    echo $value1 . '<br />';
    foreach ($parent[1] as $key2 => $value2) {
        echo '-- ' . $value2 . '<br />';
        foreach ($parent[2] as $key3 => $value3) {
            echo '---- ' . $value3 . '<br />';
        }
    }
}
```

I can do this with nested foreach loops as above but my problem is that I don't know how many parents I will have for a given query. So, how can I create a variable number of nested foreach loops... I am sure there is a better way.

Thanks for any input/advice.

Comment: That's what recursion is for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$parent[0] = array("p1v1","p1v2");  
$parent[1] = array("p2v1","p2v2","p2v3");  
$parent[2] = array("p3v1","p3v2");

function print_nested_array($parent,$level=0) {
    foreach($parent[$level] as $value) {        
        if($level > 0) {
            foreach(range(0,$level-1) as $j) {
                echo '--';
            }

            echo ' ';
        }            

        echo $value . "\n"; //change to "<br>" for html

        if($level < count($parent)-1)
            print_nested_array($parent,($level+1));
    }
}

print_nested_array($parent,0);
```

[**Demo**](http://codepad.org/Yh8pkrQ9)